# How to create Geometric shapes in JavaFX 2.0?

Tags: java, shapes, geometry, javafx-2

I have a project i am working on JavaFX 2.0, and it is a Drawing Application. I created so far a Pen, and a pen size slider, color picker, eraser and Undo functions. I do not know yet how to create basic Shapes like Rectangle, Circles or Polygons. The shapes must hape custom dimension and i need to draw them into my scene. Can anyone help me out?

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the API Docs: [javafx.scene.shape.Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html).
Sample usage: [Draw Rectangle](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/02/javafx-20-exercise-draw-rectangle.html). Circle and Line examples also exist there.

Comment: Maybe i did not exaplain myself very clearly. I need to build custom rectangles and circles. Thanks

Comment: I mean i am on my canvas. I drag the mouse and the rectangle is being created!

Comment: If you able to draw line with pen then you can draw a `Shape` instead of path/line in a same manner using mouse events, I think. The difference is you should remove the drawn shape and redraw new one while mouse move event until the mouse is released.

Comment: I have tried                                     
                rect = new Rectangle();
                rect.setMouseTransparent(true);
                rect.setStrokeWidth(sampleLine.getStrokeWidth());
                rect.setStroke(canvas.getFill());
                lineGroup.getChildren().add(rect);
                rect.getElements().add(new MoveTo(me.getSceneX(), me.getSceneY()));
                                                                      The problem is that rectangle doesn't have getElements. And i get error on the last line! And it is done with mouse effect.

Comment: You may think that the `Rectangle` has its own `PathElements` list automatically. So setting the rectangle properties is enough: `r.setX(me.getSceneX());
r.setY(me.getSceneY());` where me is fisrt click coordinate, and probably calculating the 
`r.setWidth(width);
r.setHeight(height);` according to mouse movements.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyCanvas extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
         primaryStage.setTitle(MyCanvas.class.getSimpleName());
         Group root = new Group();
         final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);
         GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
         drawShapes(gc);
         final Text text = new Text("X =    Y =   ");
         text.setTranslateX(100);
         text.setTranslateY(40);
         text.setFont(new Font(20));
         canvas.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

             @Override
             public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                 text.setText("X = " + t.getX() + "  Y = " + t.getY());
             }
         });

         root.getChildren().addAll(canvas, text);
         primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
         primaryStage.getScene().setFill(Color.AQUA);
         primaryStage.show();

     }

     /**
      * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
      * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
      * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
      * support. NetBeans ignores main().
      *
      * @param args the command line arguments
      */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }

     private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {
         gc.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
         gc.fillRect(gc.getCanvas().getLayoutX(),      
                     gc.getCanvas().getLayoutY(), 
                     gc.getCanvas().getWidth(), 
                     gc.getCanvas().getHeight());
         gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
         gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);

         gc.setLineWidth(5);
         gc.strokeLine(40, 10, 10, 40);
         gc.fillOval(10, 60, 30, 30);
         gc.strokeOval(60, 60, 30, 30);
         gc.fillRoundRect(110, 60, 30, 30, 10, 10);
         gc.strokeRoundRect(160, 60, 30, 30, 10, 10);
         gc.fillArc(10, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.OPEN);
         gc.fillArc(60, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.CHORD);
         gc.strokeArc(10, 160, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.OPEN);

     }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the graphic component of the component where you want to draw in.

if you have a panel it will be something like:

```
 Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
 Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
```

Graphics2D offers you all the methods to draw what you are looking for.
For a list off the completes methods check the docs at oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Edit: Confused JavaSE. For JavaFX you can read a little how-to here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/howto/Shapes-Tutorial.html

Comment: I need something for JavaFX 2.0, not for JavaSE. Thanks anyway for answer.

Comment: Oh sorry i just confused. But i found you a really good page by oracle also where they do explain how to do the basic figures and it looks pretty simpleactually: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/howto/Shapes-Tutorial.html

Comment: Yes, it is JavaFX, but is JavaFX 1.3! I need for 2.0! Thanks